# How to use display:flex in CSS to create a mix of fixed with and dynamic proportional width columns?

Tags: css

I'm kind of new latecomers about the `display:flex` thing in CSS. I want to create a table with 9 column, where I want some column has fixed width, and some column has dynamic proportional width against other dynamic proportional width column. All the content will always one line, and overflow content will be truncated with ellipsis. As for now, I used javascript plugin to do that. But after I accidentally stumbles into this `display:flex`, I'm thinking I'm going to change it into this, because using javascript is very heavy if the table is huge.

But I'm confused on how to do that. Basically I read that you need to have container (`<tr>`?) with `display:flex`, where the column (`<td>`?) is getting order value.

What I need is something like this:
Col 1: 100px
Col 2: 100px
Col 3: 200px
Col 4: 15% remaining dynamic length
Col 5: 20% remaining dynamic length
Col 6: 35% remaining dynamic length
Col 7: 40% remaining dynamic length
Col 8: 100px
Col 9: 250px

And my code is a simple table:

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="selectall()"</input></td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Notes</td>
        <td>Score</td>
        <td>Option Button</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="CR-10234"></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>CR-10234</td>
        <td>Maxwell, Harry</td>
        <td>Harrison, Ohio</td>
        <td>IT Engineering with 3 years experience in web programming</td>
        <td>Currently stays in San Fransisco. Need 3 days in advance to book a schedule.</td>
        <td>89</td>
        <td>
             <input type="button" onclick="edit('CR-10234')">Edit</input>
             <input type="button" onclick="delete('CR-10234')">Delete</input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I add the display flex thing? Do I need to add style attribute / class attribute to each `<td>` for each `<tr>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox isn't really intended for use on tables. You'd be better off rebuilding the whiole thing with divs if you really need to use flexbox.

Also, flexbox doesn't do % of remaining width automatically

You could use `calc` however on your existing table. No need for flexbox at all.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border:1px solid grey;
}

td:nth-child(1), 
td:nth-child(2), 
td:nth-child(8)  {
width: 100px;   /* total 300px */
background: plum;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
width: 200px; 
  background: #c0ffee;
}

td:nth-child(9) {
width: 250px;  
}

/* total fixed widths = 750px */

td:nth-child(4) {
width: calc((100% - 750px) * .15);  
  background: #bada55;
}

td:nth-child(5) {
width: calc((100% - 750px) * .2);  
}

td:nth-child(6) {
width: calc((100% - 750px) * .35);  
}

td:nth-child(7) {
width: calc((100% - 750px) * .45);  
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="selectall()"</input></td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Notes</td>
        <td>Score</td>
        <td>Option Button</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/OyQbpR)

Comment: Ooh, I never know CSS could perform calculation inside of style definition! Definitely will try it. I'll let you know. Thanks!